# Realtek Wifi is Not Working on Xubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, 18.04, realtek, wifi-direct

I have just installed latest **Xubuntu 18.04 LTS** on my new purchased low config laptop along side Windows 10 (duel boot). Everything of Installation was working fine but the Wifi is not working. Sometimes (rarely) i was able to connect to my wifi router but the network strength is too much week. My laptop uses **realtek driver (may be RTL8723BU**) for wifi. It is working fine in Windows 10 system. From inxi -Fxz command I found that my Network card not installed somehow. In Xumuntu I am now totally without internet. Here I want to add that I have no Wired LAN option in this laptop.

**How can I fix / solve this wifi / network card problem??**

Here's the output of **inxi -Fxz**

```
boundule@BUDDY:~$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: BUDDY Kernel: 4.15.0-30-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.3.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 (Gtk 2.24.31)
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Walton product: Prelude R1 serial: N/A
           Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: WH-BI-14-Y116AR120-105-C date: 03/13/2018
CPU:       Dual core Intel Celeron N3350 (-MCP-) arch: N/A cache: 1024 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 4377
           clock speeds: max: 2400 MHz 1: 869 MHz 2: 861 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 5a85 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 500 (Broxton 2x6)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Render: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster
           driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:0e.0
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-30-generic
Network:   Card: Failed to Detect Network Card!
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1008.2GB (1.2% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: HGST_HTS541010B7 size: 1000.2GB
           ID-2: USB /dev/sdb model: Transcend_8GB size: 8.0GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 19G used: 4.6G (27%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
           ID-2: /home size: 35G used: 51M (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda9
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 6.14GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda8
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 49.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 166 Uptime: 37 min Memory: 397.8/3778.5MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 7.3.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.4.191) inxi: 2.3.56
```

Here's the output of **lspci; lsusb**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge (rev 0b)
00:00.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a8c (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5a85 (rev 0b)
00:0e.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster (rev 0b)
00:0f.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0b)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0b)
00:15.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI (rev 0b)
00:16.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #1 (rev 0b)
00:16.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #2 (rev 0b)
00:16.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #3 (rev 0b)
00:16.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #4 (rev 0b)
00:17.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #5 (rev 0b)
00:17.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #6 (rev 0b)
00:17.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #7 (rev 0b)
00:17.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #8 (rev 0b)
00:18.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #1 (rev 0b)
00:18.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #2 (rev 0b)
00:18.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #3 (rev 0b)
00:18.3 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #4 (rev 0b)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #1 (rev 0b)
00:19.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #2 (rev 0b)
00:19.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #3 (rev 0b)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller (rev 0b)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface (rev 0b)
00:1f.1 SMBus: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0b)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:5608 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here's the output of **usb-devices | awk '/b720/' RS=**

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=04 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=b720 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=802.11n WLAN Adapter
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 6 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8xxxu
```

**the problem still exist after running the command & reboot.**

```
boundule@BUDDY:~$ sudo apt install build-essential dkms
[sudo] password for boundule: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
build-essential set to manually installed.
Suggested packages:
  menu
The following packages will be upgraded:
  dkms
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 68.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 19.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://bd.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 dkms all 2.3-3ubuntu9.2 [68.0 kB]
Fetched 68.0 kB in 3s (19.6 kB/s)
(Reading database ... 185574 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.3-3ubuntu9.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.2) over (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11) ...
Setting up dkms (2.3-3ubuntu9.2) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/dkms/framework.conf ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/dkms/template-dkms-mkdeb/debian/control ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
boundule@BUDDY:~$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
Cloning into 'rtl8723bu'...
remote: Counting objects: 2438, done.
remote: Total 2438 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2438
Receiving objects: 100% (2438/2438), 7.41 MiB | 63.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1960/1960), done.
boundule@BUDDY:~$ cd rtl8723bu
boundule@BUDDY:~/rtl8723bu$ source dkms.conf
boundule@BUDDY:~/rtl8723bu$ sudo mkdir /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
boundule@BUDDY:~/rtl8723bu$ sudo cp -r core hal include os_dep platform dkms.conf Makefile rtl8723b_fw.bin /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
boundule@BUDDY:~/rtl8723bu$ sudo dkms add $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723bu/4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40/source ->
                 /usr/src/rtl8723bu-4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40

DKMS: add completed.
boundule@BUDDY:~/rtl8723bu$ sudo dkms autoinstall $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=4.15.0-30-generic -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtl8723bu/4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40/build..........................
Signing module:
Generating a new Secure Boot signing key:
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
...............................................+++
...........+++
writing new private key to '/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv'
-----
 - /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723bu/4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40/4.15.0-30-generic/x86_64/module/rtl8723bu.ko
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

rtl8723bu.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod......

DKMS: install completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j2 KERNELRELEASE=4.15.0-30-generic -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-30-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtlwifi-new-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-30-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtlwifi-new/0.10/build/make.log for more information.
boundule@BUDDY:~/rtl8723bu$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep analysis with the help of chili555 & other different source My problem was solved by Following way:

**1st Step:**

```
sudo apt install build-essential dkms
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
sudo apt install libelf-dev
```

**2nd Step:**

```
sudo -i
echo blacklist rtl8xxxu >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

This ensured that the old driver was not be used for my device. In my case the problematic driver was rtl8xxxu. So I black listed it.

**3rd Step:**
Now I disabled a line in the makefile of the new driver, because without this hack, two instances of the wireless chipset was shown in Network Manager (as like chili555's Edit 3)

```
cd rtl8723bu
nano Makefile
```

Go down to line 21 and change this line:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

To comment it out, like this:

```
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

**4th Step:**
Now build and install the driver:

```
source dkms.conf
sudo mkdir /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo cp -r core hal include os_dep platform dkms.conf Makefile rtl8723b_fw.bin /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo dkms add $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo dkms autoinstall $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
```

**5th Step:**
Finally, install the compiled module with this command:

```
make
sudo make install
```

***Reboot your computer.***

Answer (score 1):

Your device uses the driver 8723bu. It must be compiled from source code. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt install build-essential dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu.git
cd rtl8723bu
source dkms.conf
sudo mkdir /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo cp -r core hal include os_dep platform dkms.conf Makefile rtl8723b_fw.bin /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo dkms add $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo dkms autoinstall $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
```

Reboot. If secure boot is enabled, it must be disabled to load an out-of-kernel module.

**EDIT**: Quite often, the weak signal is a symptom of the antenna wire being connected to connection #1 on the card when the default driver is expecting to see the signal at connection #2. Of course, you could open the laptop and switch the wire or you could add a driver parameter that permits antenna selection at the driver level.

```
sudo -i
echo “options 8723bu rtw_ant_num=1”  >  /etc/modprobe.d/8723bu.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

If this is ineffective, repeat the process with rtw_ant_num=2. Reboot.

**EDIT 2**: We see that the router you prefer is set to use TKIP encryption as well as WPA and WPA2 mixed mode. Please change the settings in the router.

WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, let’s try every setting in the driver that may possibly be useful and test:

```
sudo modprobe -r 8723bu
sudo modprobe 8723bu rtw_ant_num=2
```

Now test:

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

Is your preferred router now at a better strength? If not, try:

```
sudo modprobe -r 8723bu
sudo modprobe 8723bu rtw_ant_num=3
```

Now test:

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

Is your preferred router now at a better strength? If not, try:

```
sudo modprobe -r 8723bu
sudo modprobe 8723bu rtw_ant_num=1
```

...which was the original setting that you set.

If none of these steps are useful, I suggest that you file an issue with the author of the driver here: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu/issues

**EDIT 3**: We are going to make an amendment to the Makefile. First, we need to remove the module; next, change the Makefile and finally, rebuild.

From the terminal:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8723bu/4.3.6.11_12942.20141204_BTCOEX20140507-4E40 --all
```

Now navigate to the location where you git cloned the driver; perhaps it was your home directory:

```
cd ~/rtl8723bu
git pull
nano Makefile
```

Go down to line 21 and change this line:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

To comment it out, like this:

```
#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DCONFIG_CONCURRENT_MODE
```

Proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Now rebuild and install the driver:

```
source dkms.conf
sudo mkdir /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo cp -r core hal include os_dep platform dkms.conf Makefile rtl8723b_fw.bin /usr/src/$PACKAGE_NAME-$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo dkms add $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
sudo dkms autoinstall $PACKAGE_NAME/$PACKAGE_VERSION
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82381/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-realtek-wifi-is-not-working-on-xubuntu-18-04-lt).